# Is the default color for axis label black in `RegionPlot`?

Tags: plotting, color

I had no suspect that the default color for axis label and ticks would be black. However, after exporting an image to pdf, it seems that these colors are not black for me. Indeed, by checking the color with mspaint, the RGB value is (102,102,102).

The following is the code used to generate a plot:

```
cm = 72/2.54;
r = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, FrameLabel -> {x, y}]
Export["test1.pdf", Show[r, ImageSize -> 7 cm]]
```

The following is the part of the resulting plot that I magnified:

[image]

It does not seem as the real black. Is it the expected behavior? How can I make the color "true" black, with RGB (255,255,255)?

Comment: You can add the option FrameStyle -> Black, which also allows for other kinds of customizations, please see the Help.

Comment: @HansOlo Thanks, I checked that works. However, it is still very surprising to me that the default color is not black!

Comment: I think the default is Gray, at least in some recent versions of MMA that I have checked.

Comment: You can see the current default values on your system using `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, #}] & /@ {"GraphicsAxes", "GraphicsFrame", "GraphicsTicks", "GraphicsLabel"}`. If you did nothing strange, they should all include the color specification `GrayLevel[0.4]` somewhere

Comment: Easier to read version of @Lucas Lang's comment. `AssociationMap[
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, #}] &, {"GraphicsAxes",  "GraphicsFrame", "GraphicsTicks", "GraphicsLabel"}] // Dataset`

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question of why the default isn't black, it looks like it's to emphasize what's being plotted instead of the frame. From [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-visualization/new-default-styles.html) it says "Axes and frames have been lightened slightly to shift emphasis to the actual data."

In addition to the comment Hans made about `FrameStyle -> Black`, I might also recommend using a `Directive` to thicken the frame like `FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]`, if you really want a bold, black frame.

Looking at `PlotTheme` might also be useful. For example, you might be interested in `PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"`.

Also, check out [Graphics Options and Styling](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphicsOptionsAndStyling.html) for lots of other options.